# $\epsilon -n_0$ argument for convergence of $(3n^2+5)/(2n^2-1)$ to $3/2$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I was doing the proof to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exist an $n_
0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that etc.. And I chose my $n_0 > \max\lbrace2,\sqrt{(13+ \epsilon)/\epsilon} \rbrace$. But, is this correct?

I have that given an $\epsilon > 0$, choose $n_0 > \max\lbrace2,\sqrt{(13+ \epsilon)/\epsilon} \rbrace$. Then for all $n \ge n_0$, we have

$$\bigg|\frac{3n^2+5}{2n^2-1} - \frac{3}{2}\bigg| = \bigg| \frac{13}{2(2n^2-1)}\bigg| < \frac{13}{n^2-1}$$

but I am little confused for what to do next... What is the method?

And if not, how should I go about choosing my $n_0$ for situations similar to this?

Comment: Note that if $n\geq n_0$, then $13/(n^2-1) <\epsilon$

Comment: Thanks for the edits you guys, it is much more readable. Could you explain a little more? @John

Comment: Note that $n > \sqrt{\frac{13+\epsilon}{\epsilon}}$ is the same as $\frac{13}{n^2-1} <\epsilon$.

Comment: so, if I choose $n_0>\sqrt{(14+\epsilon)/\epsilon}$, then, would this work?

Comment: Yes, it works. Actually even $\sqrt{(13+\epsilon)/\epsilon}$ would do.

Comment: so, how do I go about completing my chain of inequalities I have, above?

Comment: You've shown that if $n\geq n_0$, then $|\frac{3n^2+5}{2n^2-1} -\frac{3}{2}| <\epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ can be chose to be arbitrarily small, $\frac{3n^2+5}{2n^2-1}$ converges to $3/2$ by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusting your computations,
you have
$$
\bigg|\frac{3n^2+5}{2n^2-1} - \frac{3}{2}\bigg|
= \bigg| \frac{13}{2(2n^2-1)}\bigg| 
\le \frac{13}{n^2} < \epsilon
$$
with the last equality being true as soon as 
$$
n > n_\epsilon := \sqrt\frac{13}\epsilon
$$
This is not the most accurate bound, but this is quick to find.